# How to retrieve text of TextView[] from viewpager within main Activity {NPE}

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `TextView[]` object and a `String[]` field in a Fragment. I have 5 Fragments in total, all handled by a ViewPager. I want to retrieve pretty much all of the Strings displayed in each Fragment (and save it to a text file later) from the click of the parent activity's menu.

Anyway, here is some code:

This is within the main Activity (only working on retrieving data from first fragment):

```
private Intent createShareIntent() {

    DisplayFragment displayFragment = (DisplayFragment) mAdapter.getItem(2);

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

    // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide what to do
    // with it.
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Display Info");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, displayFragment.retrieveContent());

    return shareIntent;
}
```

The NullPointerException comes from this method within DisplayFragment:

```
public class DisplayFragment extends Fragment {
static String devDensity, devDensityCategory, devDpi, devXDpi, devYDpi,
        devPxWidth, devPxHeight, devRefreshRate, devOrientation;
static TextView tvDispDensity, tvDensityCategory, tvDispDpi, tvDispXDpi,
        tvDispYDpi, tvDispPxWidth, tvDispPxHeight, tvDispRefreshRate,
        tvOrientation;

DisplayMetrics metrics;

// For sharing information via e-mail/SMS
/**
 * Final Content of display info
 */
String displayInfoContent;

/**
 * All textviews used in for-loop to getText()
 */
private TextView[] textViews;

private String[] strings;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getMetrics(metrics);

    devDensity = String.valueOf(metrics.density);
    devDpi = String.valueOf(metrics.densityDpi);
    devXDpi = String.valueOf(metrics.xdpi);
    devYDpi = String.valueOf(metrics.ydpi);
    devPxWidth = String.valueOf(metrics.widthPixels);
    devPxHeight = String.valueOf(metrics.heightPixels);
    devRefreshRate = String.valueOf(getActivity().getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getRefreshRate());

    translate();

    // Displays
    tvDispDensity = (TextView) getView()
            .findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayDensity);
    tvDispDensity.setText(devDensity);

    tvDensityCategory = (TextView) getView().findViewById(
            R.id.tvDensityCategory);
    tvDensityCategory.setText(devDensityCategory);

    tvDispDpi = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayDpi);
    tvDispDpi.setText(devDpi);

    tvDispXDpi = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayXDpi);
    tvDispXDpi.setText(devXDpi);

    tvDispYDpi = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayYDpi);
    tvDispYDpi.setText(devYDpi);

    tvDispPxWidth = (TextView) getView()
            .findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayWidthPx);
    tvDispPxWidth.setText(devPxWidth + " px");

    tvDispPxHeight = (TextView) getView().findViewById(
            R.id.tvDisplayHeightPx);
    tvDispPxHeight.setText(devPxHeight + " px");

    tvDispRefreshRate = (TextView) getView().findViewById(
            R.id.tvDisplayRefreshRate);
    tvDispRefreshRate.setText(devRefreshRate + " Hz");

    tvOrientation = (TextView) getView().findViewById(
            R.id.tvDisplayOrientation);
    tvOrientation.setText(devOrientation);
    //
    // #################################
    textViews = new TextView[]{tvDispDensity, tvDensityCategory, tvDispDpi, tvDispXDpi,
            tvDispYDpi, tvDispPxWidth, tvDispPxHeight, tvDispRefreshRate,
            tvOrientation};

    strings = new String[]{devDensity, devDensityCategory, devDpi, devXDpi, devYDpi,
            devPxWidth, devPxHeight, devRefreshRate, devOrientation};
}

private void translate() {
    switch (metrics.densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            devDensityCategory = "Low (120 dpi)";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            devDensityCategory = "Medium (160 dpi)";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            devDensityCategory = "High (240 dpi)";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            devDensityCategory = "XHigh (320 dpi)";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
            devDensityCategory = "XXHigh (480 dpi)";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
            devDensityCategory = "XXXHigh (640 dpi)";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
            devDensityCategory = "TV (213 dpi)";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_400:
            devDensityCategory = "Intermediate (400 dpi)";
            break;

        default:
            devDensityCategory = "Unknown";
            break;
    }

    switch (getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation()) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            devOrientation = "0°";
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            devOrientation = "90°";
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            devOrientation = "180°";
            break;

        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            devOrientation = "270°";
            break;

        default:
            devOrientation = "Unknown";
            break;
    }

}

public String retrieveContent() {
    String content = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < textViews.length; i++) {
        content += (textViews[i].getText() + " = " + strings[i] + "\n");
    }
    return content;
}
```

Are the Arrays initialized when the Fragment is off-screen? If not, how could I pull this off otherwise?

Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at my.package.name.fragments.DisplayFragment.retrieveContent(DisplayFragment.java:170)
```

which is this `content += (textViews[i].getText() + " = " + strings[i] + "\n");` in my for loop.

Any insight will be greatly appreciated, thank you for reading.

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

> Are the Arrays initialized when the Fragment is off-screen? If not, how could I pull this off otherwise?

The problem is when the Fragment is off-screen, the fragment itself might not have been created at all. By default, the view pager only initialize the previous and next page of the current page. For example, if you are active on page 1, only page 2 will be initialized by default. if you are on third page, then only 2nd, 3rd and 4th pages are created.

To pull this of otherwise? you can just simply set the off screen page limit to 4, so that it will make sure that it will keep 4 pages next or previous of your current page (in your case, all 5 fragments will be created at once)

```
urViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

put that code in the OnCreate on the activity after your initialization of urViewPager.
Hope this helps, cheer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already have tried that and doesn't work :( I added my whole DisplayFragment, maybe there's something I'm overlooking or not understanding...

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. Apparently the TextView[] was not initialized properly. Insted of having it in OnActivityCreated(), I initialized TextView[] and String[] directly in retrieveInfo() method of fragment. Also made textview fields static variables and works like a charm

```
public String retrieveContent() {
textViews = new TextView[]{tvDispDensity, tvDensityCategory, tvDispDpi, tvDispXDpi,
        tvDispYDpi, tvDispPxWidth, tvDispPxHeight, tvDispRefreshRate,
        tvOrientation};

strings = new String[]{devDensity, devDensityCategory, devDpi, devXDpi, devYDpi,
        devPxWidth, devPxHeight, devRefreshRate, devOrientation};

String content = "";
for (int i = 0; i < textViews.length; i++) {
    content += (textViews[i].getText() + " = " + strings[i] + "\n");
}
return content;
}
```

Works just fine now :)